# Pandas: Calculate percentage of column for each class

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Class   Boolean  Sum
0       1         0  10
1       1         1  20
2       2         0  15
3       2         1  25
4       3         0  52
5       3         1  48
```

I want to calculate percentage of 0/1's for each class, so for example the output could be:

```
   Class   Boolean  Sum  %
0       1         0  10  0.333
1       1         1  20  0.666
2       2         0  15  0.375
3       2         1  25  0.625
4       3         0  52  0.520
5       3         1  48  0.480
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide column `Sum` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return Series with same length as original DataFrame filled by aggregated values:

```
df['%'] = df['Sum'].div(df.groupby('Class')['Sum'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
   Class  Boolean  Sum         %
0      1        0   10  0.333333
1      1        1   20  0.666667
2      2        0   15  0.375000
3      2        1   25  0.625000
4      3        0   52  0.520000
5      3        1   48  0.480000
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('Class')['Sum'].transform('sum'))
0     30
1     30
2     40
3     40
4    100
5    100
Name: Sum, dtype: int64
```